# concurrent.futures not parallelizing my code

Tags: python, concurrency, concurrent.futures

why concurrent.futures not working in this code, means it's not parallelizing the task, when i run the code its working basically(not multiprocessing)please help me in this

```
    import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import concurrent.futures
from csv import reader
from bs4 import SoupStrainer as strainer
urls = []
titles = []
cost = []
import lxml


def transform(url, TrackingPrice):
    r = requests.get(str(url))
    only_item_cells = strainer("div", attrs={"class": "_30jeq3 _16Jk6d"})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml', parse_only= only_item_cells)
    ajay = soup.text
    price = ajay.replace("₹", "").replace(",", "")
    print(price, TrackingPrice)
            
    return

df=pd.read_csv("C:/Users\\Sudip\\Downloads\\flip.csv")
for i in range(0,len(df["URL"])):
    transform(df["URL"][i], df["TrackingPrice"][i])
    
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(transform, urls)
```

Answer (score 0):

"The asynchronous execution can be performed with threads, using ThreadPoolExecutor, or separate processes, using ProcessPoolExecutor. Both implement the same interface, which is defined by the abstract Executor class." --> https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html

You may want to use ProcessPoolExecutor (Threads in python is managed by GIL not by the OS himself, so that it will only handle a pseudo parralelism in one fork). Processes in Python, means fork another process.